# Fetch images using PHAsset with fetch limit (pagination)

Tags: swift, pagination, phasset

I have a function in my app which is supposed to get all the images stored in users phone as they scroll down however i am having difficulty trying to implement that. so far my code gets only the first 30 images and repeats that over and over again and i'm unsure how to get it to fetch the first 30 and then the next 30 and so on. 
I've tried setting the "photos.firstObject" to say the last object of the images array but its telling me that firstObject is a getOnly property. Thanks in advance, Here's my code

```
func fetchPhotos() {
    let assetfetch = PHFetchOptions()
    assetfetch.fetchLimit = 30
    let photos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: assetfetch)

    // calls the code in the background thread
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        photos.enumerateObjects({ (asset, count, stop) in

            // size of the fetched images
            let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
            let targetSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
            //print(asset.creationDate)
            // display better quality thumbnail image
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.isSynchronous = true
            // gets the image and appends them to the arrays
            imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: { (image, info) in

                if let image = image {
                    self.images.append(image)
                    self.assets.append(asset)

                    // sets the first image as the default selected image
                    if self.selectedImage == nil {
                        self.selectedImage = image
                    }
                }
                // when the photos count reaches 29, reload the collection view to fill the photos
                if count == photos.count - 1 {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
} 


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! photoSelectorCell

    cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.item]
    if indexPath.item == self.images.count - 1 {
        fetchPhotos()

    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why you stored all the image object in an array? It causes memory issue to have all the images in the array.
Try to make the asset object array and fetch image in `cellForItemAt indexPath `

Comment: Fetch Images With Pagination .
How to get it to fetch the first 10 and then the next 10 and so on.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560446/how-to-paginate-when-using-phasset-to-fetch-user-photo-library